# How to prevent form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a login form and a captcha field. I need a  javascript source to check this captcha input then send post data to action but my code seems to be wrong, the e.preventDefault function doesn't work because captcha field true or false post data's still sent. please help.

**This my javascript Function:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#signupform").submit(function (event) {        
    var captchacode = $("#captchatexbox").val();
    if (captchacode != "") {
        var url = "/Account/ValidateCaptcha?Code=" + captchacode;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 0) {

                    alert("Invalid captcha");
                    event.preventDefault();
                    //Form post data still sent?
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else alert("Captcha not null");
   });
});
```

Comment: You should move ```event.preventDefault()``` to be before ```var captchacode = ...``` because you're making an ajax request and since you're waiting on the response, the preventDefault won't get called

Comment: you should put event.preventDefault(); before you initialise captchacode

Comment: @BrianPutt you won me by 5 secs lol

Comment: @Raymond, Alex beat me by ~5 secs too :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move `event.preventDefault();` up so it comes before the ajax call.

Use `$("#signupform").submit();` in an else block to programmatically submit the form.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#signupform").submit(function (event) {        
    event.preventDefault();
    var captchacode = $("#captchatexbox").val();
    if (captchacode != "") {
        var url = "/Account/ValidateCaptcha?Code=" + captchacode;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 0) {
                    alert("Invalid captcha");
                    //Form post data still sent?
                } else {
                    $("#signupform").submit();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else alert("Captcha not null");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need have the form event.preventDefault(); before making the ajax request.

`$("#signupform").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();`

When the ajax request is returned, you can submit the form using:

`if (data != 0) {
    $("#signupform").submit();
}`